# cmake: qt resources inside a module

Tags: qt, resources, qt4, cmake

i have this tree structure:

```
repository/modules/module1
repository/modules/module2
repository/modules/module..
repository/apps/application1
repository/apps/application2
repository/apps/application..
```

where the applications are using some modules.

now, I'd like to put some resources inside a module (like a very colorfull icons inside a widget used by several applications) but.. something gets wrong.

inside the module CMakeLists.txt if I use only:

```
set(${MODULE_NAME}_RCS
    colors.qrc
)

...
qt4_add_resources   (${MODULE_NAME}_RHEADERS ${${MODULE_NAME}_RCS})
```

no **qrc_colors.cxx** are created anywhere. so I've tried to add:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE (${MODULE_NAME}
    ${${MODULE_NAME}_RHEADERS}
)
```

but.. I get this weird error:

```
CMake Error at repo/modules/ColorModule/CMakeLists.txt:51 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
  add_executable cannot create target "ColorModule" because another
  target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a static
  library created in source directory
  "repo/modules/ColorModule".  See documentation for
  policy CMP0002 for more details.
```

(I've changed the path of the error of course)

so.. don't know what to think because i'm new both to cmake and qt..

what can i try?

## EDIT:

if I add the `${MODULE_NAME}_RHEADERS` and `${MODULE_NAME}_RCS` in the add_library command the **qrc_colors.cxx** is created BUT it is in repository/modules/module1/built and not copied in the application built directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least two errors in your code.

1) It is usually not necessary to use ${MODULE_NAME} everywhere like that, just "MODULE_NAME". You can see that the difference is the raw string vs. variable. It is usually recommended to avoid double variable value dereference if possible.

2) More importantly, you seem to be setting ${MODULE_NAME} in more than one executable place, which is "ColorModule" according to the error output. You should have individual executable names for different binaries.

Also, the resource file focus is a bit of red herring in here. There are several other issues with your project.

- You can cmake files as CmakeLists.txt instead of CMakeLists.txt which inherently causes issues on case sensitive systes as my Linux box.
- You use Findfoo.cmake, and find_package(foo) for that matter, rather than the usual FindFoo.cmake convention alongside find_package(Foo).
- Your FindFoo.cmake is quite odd, and you should probably be rewritten.
- Most importantly, you should use config files rather than find modules.

Documentation and examples can be found at these places:

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials#CMake_Packages

https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdeexamples/repository/revisions/master/show/buildsystem

When you would like use a find module, you need to have that at hand already. That will tell you what to look for, where things are, or if they are not anywhere where necessary. It is not something that you should write. You should just reuse existing ones for those projects that are not using cmake, and hence the find modules are added separately.

It is a bit like putting the treasure map just next to the treasure. Do you understand the irony? :) Once you find the map, you would automatically have the treasure as well. i.e. you would not look for it anymore.